# Proof about "metric measure on a compact metric space"

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm reading 
*Edgar - Measure, topology, and fractal geometry - 2008*; page 157

> **Proposition 5.4.3.** Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a finite metric measure on a compact metric space $S$. Let $E ⊆ S$ be a Borel set. For any $ε > 0$, there exist a compact set $K$ and an open set $U$ with $U ⊇ E ⊇ K$ and $\mathcal{M}(U \ K) < ε$.

In the proof a closed set $F$ is taken and the following sequence is defined
$$
U_n =\{ x ∈ S : dist(x, F )<1/n\}.
$$
Clearly, $U_n\downarrow$ and $\bigcap U_n=F$.
Then the author says
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{M}(U_n)=\mathcal{M}(F)
$$
I understand that $U_n\supseteq F$, thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{M}(U_n)\ge\mathcal{M}(F)$, but where the converse comes from?

Comment: Presumably you mean $\bigcap U_n = F$

Comment: It might help if you gave the definition of a "metric measure" in this context. I haven't heard of it and I don't know if it's well-known

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for signaling the typo.

Comment: What the author is speaking about is a metric outer measure; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_outer_measure ; it seams to me (beginner) that it is not a introductory topic, but it is a standard (not debated) topic; the few definitions that I have seen (included the linked from wikipedia) are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if we have nested measurable sets $\{ U_{n} \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $U_{n} \supset U_{n+1} \supset U_{n+2} \supset \dots$, and there is an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathcal{M}(U_{m}) < \infty$, then it follows that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal{M}(U_{n}) = \mathcal{M}(\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_{n})$. Since the $U_{n}$ as defined satisfies that $\mathcal{M}(U_{1}) \leq \mathcal{M}(S) < \infty$, and $\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_{n} = F$, it follows that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal{M}(U_{n}) = \mathcal{M}(\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_{n}) = \mathcal{M}(F)$. 
 
The proof of the first sentence is as follows: Define $G_{n} = U_{n} \setminus U_{n+1}$. Then $U_{1} = (\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_{n}) \cup (\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}G_{n})$. Let $U = \cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_{n}$. Since the $G_{n}$'s are disjoint, we obtain that $\mu(U_{1}) = \mu(U) + \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mu(U_{n}) - \mu(U_{n+1}) = \mu(U) + \mu(U_{1}) - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(U_{n})$. Since $\mu(U_{1}) < \infty$, we may subtract on both sides to obtain that $\mu(\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_{n} ) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(U_{n})$. 
Edit: 
The proof I have given also applies to this example because $U_{n}$ is an open set and Borel Sets are measurable in the Caratheodory sense with respect to the metric outer measure. It will be sufficient to show that $\forall F \subset S$, $F$ closed, $\forall A \subset X$, $\mathcal{M}(A) = \mathcal{M}(A \cap F) + \mathcal{M}(A \setminus F)$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is the metric outer measure. Define $A_{n} = \{ x \in A : d(x,F) \geq \frac{1}{n} \}$. Observe that $A \setminus F = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n} $. Note that $\mathcal{M}(A) \leq \mathcal{M}(A \cap F) + \mathcal{M}(A \setminus F)$ by monotonicity. Observe that for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, since $A_{n}$ and $F$ are positively separated, $\mathcal{M}(A \cap F) + \mathcal{M}(A_{n}) = \mathcal{M}((A \cap F) \cup A_{n}) \leq \mathcal{M}(A)$. We would like to show that $\mathcal{M}(A \setminus F) \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal{M}(A_{n})$. Assuming this, we then would have that $\mathcal{M}(A \cap F) + \mathcal{M}(A \setminus F) \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\mathcal{M}(A \cap F) + \mathcal{M}(A_{n})) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal{M}((A \cap F) \cup A_{n}) \leq \mathcal{M}(A)$, which would imply that $F$ is caratheodory measurable. Define $B_{n} = A_{n} \setminus A_{n-1}$, and $B_{1} = A_{1}$. Then $\mathcal{M}(\cup_{n=k}^{\infty} B_{2n-1}) = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \mathcal{M}(B_{2n-1})$, and $\mathcal{M}(\cup_{n=k}^{\infty} B_{2n}) = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \mathcal{M}(B_{2n})$, since they are positively separated. Note that $\mathcal{M}(\cup_{n=k}^{\infty} B_{2n}) , \mathcal{M}(\cup_{n=k}^{\infty} B_{2n-1}) \leq \mathcal{M}(A_{2k-1})$ by monotonicity. Assume $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal{M}(A_{n}) < \infty$, since if it were infinite then $\mathcal{M}(A) = \infty$ and there is nothing to prove. Then $\mathcal{M}(\cup_{n=k}^{\infty} B_{2n}) , \mathcal{M}(\cup_{n=k}^{\infty} B_{2n-1}) < \infty$. Observe that $(A \setminus F) = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n} \implies \mathcal{M}(A \setminus F) = \mathcal{M}(\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n}) \leq \mathcal{M}(A_{k} \cup (\cup_{n=k+1}^{\infty} B_{n}))$ for any fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\mathcal{M}(A \setminus F) \leq \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal{M}(A_{k})  + \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} \mathcal{M}(B_{n})$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{M}(B_{n}) < \infty \implies \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \mathcal{M}(B_{n}) = 0$. Hence, $\mathcal{M}(A \setminus F) \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal{M}(A_{n}) \implies \mathcal{M}(A \cap F) + \mathcal{M}(A \setminus F)  \leq \mathcal{M}(A \cap F) + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathcal{M}(A_{n}) \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathcal{M}((A \cap F) \cup A_{n}) \leq \mathcal{M}(A)$. Hence, $F$ is caratheodory measurable. This implies that the Borel sets of a metric space are measurable with respect to the metric outer measure. By the Caratheodory extension theorem, $\mathcal{M}$ is countably additive on the borel sets. The proof given earlier now applies to the metric outer measure.

Comment: $\mu$ and $\mathcal{M}$ are the same measure? We are working with an outer measure not necessarily countably additive, how to you obtain the countably sum of measure in the second last sentence? To have $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$ we need to prove that $A,B$ are positively separated, and only for finite meany sets not countably many; I do not think (or I do not understand why) "disjoint" is enough.

Comment: Basically, the borel sets are measurable w.r.t the metric outer measure and so it is countably additive on borel sets. Open sets are borel sets and so the proof given earlier regarding an arbitrary measure space can be replicated here. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: thank you very much. The main point for me (and I shouldn't have missed it!) is "the restriction of the outer measure to the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets is a (complete) measure (thus $\sigma$-additive), that is, your last paragraph.